# can any one help me in writting test class for this trigger?

Tags: unit-test

```
trigger updateFedexcases on FedEx_Claims_Process__c (before update) 
{

  Set<Id> CaseIds = new Set<Id>();
  list<case> caselisttoupadte = new list<case>();
  list<FedEx_Claims_Process__c> newlist = new list<FedEx_Claims_Process__c>();
  for(FedEx_Claims_Process__c a: Trigger.new)
  {
    CaseIds.add(a.Case_Number__c); 

  }

Map<Id, Case> CaseMaptoUpdate = new Map<Id,Case>([Select Id, Shipping_Method__c,Date_of_Check__c,Claim_Status__c,Claim_Comments__c,Check_Amount_of_Claim__c,Check__c from Case WHERE Id IN: CaseIds AND (Claim_Status__c= 'Open' OR Claim_Status__c= '')]);

if(CaseMaptoUpdate.size()>0)
{

for(FedEx_Claims_Process__c a: Trigger.new)
{
  a.IsUpdated__c = TRUE;
  CaseMaptoUpdate.get(a.Case_Number__c).Claim_Comments__c = a.Claim_Comments__c;
  CaseMaptoUpdate.get(a.Case_Number__c).Date_of_Check__c = a.Date_of_Check__c;
  CaseMaptoUpdate.get(a.Case_Number__c).Claim_Status__c = a.Claim_Status__c;
  CaseMaptoUpdate.get(a.Case_Number__c).Check_Amount_of_Claim__c = a.Claim_Amount_Paid__c;
  CaseMaptoUpdate.get(a.Case_Number__c).Check__c = a.Check__c;
  caselisttoupadte.add(CaseMaptoUpdate.get(a.Case_Number__c));
  newlist.add(a);
}
}

if(caselisttoupadte.size()>0)
update caselisttoupadte;
```

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Rajat. Can you please try to format your code, explain which parts you have trouble getting covered by tests (and why) and what you've already tried yourself ?

Comment: Rajat, if you can show that you've written some test code, I'm sure we'd all be happy helping you to improve it.
Do you understand the purpose of test code and how it should follow the intended execution of your production code?

Comment: before you do anything else, are you sure this shouldn't be an "after update" trigger? If you're updating a different object, usually an after trigger is required.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome in Salesforce!!!
You need to perform same thing for which you write the trigger, as if you write a trigger on `Account` and `After/before update` you perform an update on `contact` related with that `Account` then you need to insert an `Account` and a related `Contact` in test class . and then update the Account after which trigger is fired thats all.
Writing test code to invoke Apex Trigger logic is a requirement, even if you have other tests that cover other aspects of the code called from it.
As such you must have at least one Apex test perform the require DML operations on the object to invoke the trigger logic. 
I also recommend you to follow the links given in

[How to write a unit-test / test class for trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/how-to-write-a-unit-test-test-class-for-trigger)  Specially the link for [ShivaSoft](http://shivasoft.in/blog/salesforce/step-by-step-salesforce-tutorial-%E2%80%93-creating-trigger-and-test-cases-%E2%80%93-6-of-6/) blog.

All Operation Performend in Between Below Syntax :

```
  @isTest
 private class test_Class{

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
 // TO DO: implement unit test

 //Write Your Code Here

 }

 }
```

If you still have problem then let me know.