# Testing Apex Get Methods

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm having trouble testing this code. It seems so simple but I can't get it to work.It keep giving me an Attempt to de-reference a null object error.

```
public CustomSetting__c instanceVariable;
public CustomSetting__c getCustomSettingInstance(){
     return instanceVariable;
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to add the test methods but here they are

```
@isTest static void test_getConfigInstance() {
    CustomSettingCtrlr myCtrlr = new CustomSettingCtrlr ();

    myCtrlr.instanceVariable.Name = 'name';
    myCtrlr.instanceVariable.booleanField= true;
    insert myCtrlr.instanceVariable;

    Test.startTest();
        myCtrlr.getConfigInstance();
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertNotEquals(csmUtil.getConfigInstance(), null);
    System.assertEquals(myCtrlr.instanceVariable.Name, 'name');

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174857

Comment: @AdrianLarson Duplicate?

Comment: There's a little bit more going on in that post, but this scenario *is* one of the aspects of that post. Probably not worth reopening just to mark as duplicate though.

Comment: Please be more specific than *"I can't get it to work"*.

Comment: Please provide the entire code so readers can run it on their own and include your test results (I'm assuming some % code coverage, 1 failure and 0 successes). Try commenting out // System.assertNotEquals(csmUtil.getConfigInstance(), null); to see what that changes. I don't see where csm.*** comes from in the lines of code you've shared

Comment: This will  not compile as the instanceVariable is private and thus not accessible to the test method (unless you are using an OLD API and the test is in the same class). Please post the code as it is compiled AND the EXACT error message verbatim

Comment: Still will not compile - `csmUtil` is not defined and your test start and stop test block is redundant as the assert will be doing the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so aside from your code not compiling:

1. Your declaration of `instanceVariable` starts out as null

   ```
   public CustomSetting__c instanceVariable;
   ```
2. then in your test when you do the following

   ```
   myCtrlr.instanceVariable.Name = 'name';
   ```

You will get a DNO error as the variable is null

To Fix, add the following before that line

```
myCtrlr.instanceVariable = New CustomSetting__c();
```

Depending on what you are actually trying to do you may want to automate it and change the get method to the following:

```
public CustomSetting__c getCustomSettingInstance(){
     instanceVariable = CustomSetting__c.getOrgDefaults();
     //If the Id or variable is null then instantiate a new instance
     return instanceVariable;
}
```

Additionally your asserts will cause confusion as the pattern is

**EXPECTED,ACTUAL**

```
System.assertEquals('name', myCtrlr.instanceVariable.Name);
```

The way you have it reverses that order

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got it correctly i'm also a beginner but, try adding @TestVisible annotation in front of 'private CustomSetting__c instanceVariable;' in your controller.

e.g @TestVisible private CustomSetting__c instanceVariable;

then simply call the method in test class Like: 
 CustomSettingCtrlr myCtrlr = new CustomSettingCtrlr ();
 myCtrlr.getCustomSettingInstance();

Hope this will help.

Comment: So the private variable is public in my code, I accidentally wrote it in the code

Comment: static testMethod void MyTestMethod(){
    CustomSettingCtrlr CusCtrl = new CustomSettingCtrlr();
      
    CusCtrl.instanceVariable = new CustomSetting__c();
    CusCtrl.getCustomSettingInstance();
  }                         Try this and add field if necessary!