# Trying to deploy Automatic Attachment Cloning trigger between two custom objects

Tags: apex, trigger, deployment, code-coverage

I try to deploy a trigger from sandbox tp production but my test class does not fill the code coverage of the trigger it is supposed to check.

I am new to Apex (or Java) & don't know what is missing.

**Trigger**

```
trigger Copy_Attachments_from_Invoice on DATEV1__AccountingDocument__c (after insert) {
{
    Attachment[] attList = [SELECT id, name, body from Attachment where parentid = :Trigger.new[0].Supplier_Invoice__c];

    Attachment[] insertAttList = new Attachment[]{};

    for(Attachment a : attList)

    {
        Attachment attach = new Attachment(name = a.name, body = a.body, parentId = Trigger.new[0].Id);

        insertAttList.add(attach);
    }

    if(insertAttList.size() > 0)

    {
        insert insertAttList;
    }
 }
}
```

(this already works in sandbox, yay!)

**Test class**

```
@isTest

public class Test_Copy_Attachments_from_Invoice {

    static testMethod void testCopy_Attachments_from_Invoice () {

         Supplier_Invoice__c si = new Supplier_Invoice__c();

        insert si;       

        Attachment attList = [SELECT id, name, body from Attachment where parentid = :si.id];

        attList.Name       = 'Unit Test Attachment 1';

        attList.body       = Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body 1');

        attList.parentId   = si.id;



        insert attList;   



        // -- Retrieve saved & generated attachments   

        List <Attachment> attachments = [select id, name, body from Attachment where parentid=:si.id];
        List <Attachment> attachments2 = [select id, name, body from Attachment where Name = 'Unit Test Attachment 1'];

    }  

}
```

At least it doesn't show me any errors anymore after doing a lot of trial & error but when I run it it doesn't fill the code coverage.

Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a unit-test / test class for trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/how-to-write-a-unit-test-test-class-for-trigger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger will never execute because your unit test never inserts a `DATEV1__AccountingDocument__c`.

The three fundamental components of a unit test are

1. Perform data setup.
2. Execute code path under test.
3. Validate results.

This unit test currently does only (1). You must cause your code to execute, and you must write assertions to validate the results.

```
    Attachment attList = [SELECT id, name, body from Attachment where parentid = :si.id];
```

There's no data responsive to this query, and you're assigning it to a single sObject, so it will fail and throw a `QueryException`, which will cause the failure of your whole test. You need to create *all* of the required input data for the test.

Note further that your trigger will simply do nothing to any records beyond the first in the DML operation. You should read [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) and ensure that your trigger operates across *all* objects in `Trigger.new`, or you are setting your org up for loss of data integrity and inscrutable behavior in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much! It took some time but I managed to get it to work now.