# How To test my field update Trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I struggle to cover part of my code.
[image]

Could someone help?
Thanks

here is my code:

```
trigger AircallTaskTrigger on Task (after insert, after update) {

    List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();
 
    //Get 'Case Concern' RecordType Name
    Id caseConcernRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(label.Param_Case_Concern).getRecordTypeId();

    Map<Id, Case> caseWithAircallTaskMap = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, First_Aircall_Logged__c FROM Case WHERE RecordTypeId =:caseConcernRecordTypeId]);                           
    for(Task t : Trigger.New) { 
       
        if(t.whatId != null &&  t.callDisposition!= null && t.callDisposition.containsIgnoreCase('aircall')) {
           System.debug('#### Aircall debug ' + t.whatId != null && t.callDisposition.containsIgnoreCase('aircall'));
            
            Case c = New Case();
            if(caseWithAircallTaskMap != null && caseWithAircallTaskMap.containsKey(t.whatId)){
            
                c = caseWithAircallTaskMap.get(t.whatId);
                if(c.first_Aircall_Logged__c == null){
                    c.first_Aircall_Logged__c = t.createdDate;
                    if(t.WhatId == c.Id) {
                        lstCase.add(c); 
                    }              
                } 
            } 
        }     
    }
 
    if (lstCase.size() > 0) {
        update lstCase;
    }  


}
```

Here is my Test Class

```
@isTest
public class AircallTaskTriggerTest {
@isTest static void testAircallDateUpdate() {
    
    Contact con = new Contact (FirstName = 'First Name',LastName = 'Test');
    insert con;
    
    Case c = new Case(Status = 'New',ContactId = con.Id,Phone_Number__c = '123456789');
    insert c;
           
    Task t = new Task(Subject = 'Test', WhatId = c.Id, CreatedDate = System.today(), callDisposition = 'aircall');
    insert t;
    
    c.Id = t.WhatId;
    c.First_Aircall_Logged__c = null;
    //System.assertEquals(t.CreatedDate,  c.First_Aircall_Logged__c);
    update c;
   
}

}
```

Comment: It looks like the case inserted in your test class has not the right record type.

Comment: I recommend you read [this article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/how-to-write-a-unit-test-test-class-for-trigger) the main answer for which covers a number of points you should adopt (such as not writing code directly in the trigger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IsTest
public class AircallTaskTriggerTest {
    @IsTest
    static void testAircallDateUpdate() {
        Contact con = new Contact (FirstName = 'First Name', LastName = 'Test');
        insert con;

        Id caseConcernRecordTypeId =
            Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(label.Param_Case_Concern).getRecordTypeId();
        Case c = new Case(Status = 'New', ContactId = con.Id, Phone_Number__c = '123456789', **RecordTypeId = caseConcernRecordTypeId**);
        insert c;

        Task t = new Task(Subject = 'Test', WhatId = c.Id, CreatedDate = System.today(), callDisposition = 'aircall');
        insert t;

        c.Id = t.WhatId;
        c.First_Aircall_Logged__c = null;
        //System.assertEquals(t.CreatedDate,  c.First_Aircall_Logged__c);
        update c;
    }
}
```

The test class is creating a Case without a record type, I have added in the code with the specific RecordType id.

Comment: could you please add a few words what was actually wrong with the code