# APEX Trigger code coverage issue

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an APEX Trigger and a Test class, I can not get code coverage above 45%.
Any Idea what else I can add please?
(Problem is that i do not have any code coverage in else condition

```
else if (trigger.isDelete) {
```

of my APEX trigger) But how to do it in Test Class ?

Apex Trigger:

```
Trigger updateTotalExpenseCost on Expense__c(after insert, after update, after delete) {

  if (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) {

    for (Expense__c a:Trigger.new) {

      if ( a.Driver_Statement__c != null ) {

        Driver_Statement__c DriverStatement_Record = [SELECT Id, Total_EZ_I_Pass_Cost__c, Total_Fuel_Cost__c, Total_Truck_Cost__c, Total_Trailer_Cost__c, Total_Miscellaneous_Cost__c, Total_Insurance_Cost__c FROM Driver_Statement__c WHERE Id =: a.Driver_Statement__c LIMIT 1];

        List<AggregateResult> TotalsCalculationBasedOnTypeRaw = [SELECT SUM(Cost__c)TotalCost FROM Expense__c WHERE Driver_Statement__c =: DriverStatement_Record.Id AND Type__c =: a.Type__c];
        Decimal TotalCalculatedCost = (Decimal)TotalsCalculationBasedOnTypeRaw[0].get('TotalCost');

        if (a.Type__c == 'EZ/I Pass') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_EZ_I_Pass_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Fuel') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Fuel_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Miscellaneous') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Miscellaneous_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Trailer') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Trailer_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Truck') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Truck_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Insurance') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Insurance_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }


      }

    }

  } else if (trigger.isDelete) {

    for (Expense__c a:Trigger.old) {

      if ( a.Driver_Statement__c != null ) {

        Driver_Statement__c DriverStatement_Record = [SELECT Id, Total_EZ_I_Pass_Cost__c, Total_Fuel_Cost__c, Total_Truck_Cost__c, Total_Trailer_Cost__c, Total_Miscellaneous_Cost__c, Total_Insurance_Cost__c FROM Driver_Statement__c WHERE Id =: a.Driver_Statement__c LIMIT 1];

        List<AggregateResult> TotalsCalculationBasedOnTypeRaw = [SELECT SUM(Cost__c)TotalCost FROM Expense__c WHERE Driver_Statement__c =: DriverStatement_Record.Id AND Type__c =: a.Type__c];
        Decimal TotalCalculatedCost = (Decimal)TotalsCalculationBasedOnTypeRaw[0].get('TotalCost');

        if (a.Type__c == 'EZ/I Pass') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_EZ_I_Pass_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Fuel') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Fuel_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Miscellaneous') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Miscellaneous_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Trailer') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Trailer_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Truck') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Truck_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }

        if (a.Type__c == 'Insurance') {

          DriverStatement_Record.Total_Insurance_Cost__c = TotalCalculatedCost;
          update DriverStatement_Record;

        }


      }

    }

  }

}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class TestupdateTotalExpenseCost {

  @isTest static void  testIfRecordEqualFuelTrue() {

    Account AccountCreate = new Account(Name='Test Account', RecordTypeId='0121U000000WnELQA0');
    insert AccountCreate;

    Opportunity OpportunityCreate = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opportunity', StageName='Active', CloseDate=date.today(), AccountId=AccountCreate.id, RecordTypeId='0121U000000bFCr');
    insert OpportunityCreate;

    Driver_Statement__c DriverStatementCreate = new Driver_Statement__c(Name='Test Driver Statement',Opportunity__c=OpportunityCreate.id, Total_Driver_Gross_Rate__c = 1234.00);
    insert DriverStatementCreate;

    if (DriverStatementCreate.id != null) {

      Expense__c ExpenseCreate1 = new Expense__c(Type__c='Fuel', Cost__c=1235.00, Driver_Statement__c = DriverStatementCreate.id);
      insert ExpenseCreate1;

      List<AggregateResult> SearchExpenseSumFuel = [SELECT SUM(Cost__c)TotalCost FROM Expense__c WHERE Driver_Statement__c =: DriverStatementCreate.Id AND Type__c =: ExpenseCreate1.Type__c];

      List<Expense__c> SearchExpenseType = [SELECT Type__c FROM Expense__c WHERE Id =: ExpenseCreate1.Id];

      if (ExpenseCreate1.Type__c == SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c')) {

        DriverStatementCreate.Total_Fuel_Cost__c = (Decimal)SearchExpenseSumFuel[0].get('TotalCost');
        update DriverStatementCreate;

        List<Driver_Statement__c> SearchTotalFuel = [SELECT Total_Fuel_Cost__c FROM Driver_Statement__c WHERE Id =: DriverStatementCreate.Id LIMIT 1];
        
        System.assertEquals((decimal)SearchTotalFuel[0].get('Total_Fuel_Cost__c'), (decimal)SearchExpenseSumFuel[0].get('TotalCost'));

        System.assertEquals('Fuel', SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c'));

        System.assertEquals(1, SearchExpenseType.size());

      }

    }

  }

  @isTest static void  testIfRecordEqualEzPassTrue() {

    Account AccountCreate = new Account(Name='Test Account', RecordTypeId='0121U000000WnELQA0');
    insert AccountCreate;

    Opportunity OpportunityCreate = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opportunity', StageName='Active', CloseDate=date.today(), AccountId=AccountCreate.id, RecordTypeId='0121U000000bFCr');
    insert OpportunityCreate;

    Driver_Statement__c DriverStatementCreate = new Driver_Statement__c(Name='Test Driver Statement',Opportunity__c=OpportunityCreate.id, Total_Driver_Gross_Rate__c = 1234.00);
    insert DriverStatementCreate;

    if (DriverStatementCreate.id != null) {

      Expense__c ExpenseCreate1 = new Expense__c(Type__c='EZ/I Pass', Cost__c=1235.00, Driver_Statement__c = DriverStatementCreate.id);
      insert ExpenseCreate1;

      List<AggregateResult> SearchExpenseSumEZPass = [SELECT SUM(Cost__c)TotalCostEZPass FROM Expense__c WHERE Driver_Statement__c =: DriverStatementCreate.Id AND Type__c =: ExpenseCreate1.Type__c];

      List<Expense__c> SearchExpenseType = [SELECT Type__c FROM Expense__c WHERE Id =: ExpenseCreate1.Id];

      if (ExpenseCreate1.Type__c == SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c')) {

        DriverStatementCreate.Total_EZ_I_Pass_Cost__c = (Decimal)SearchExpenseSumEZPass[0].get('TotalCostEZPass');
        update DriverStatementCreate;

        List<Driver_Statement__c> SearchTotalEZPass = [SELECT Total_EZ_I_Pass_Cost__c FROM Driver_Statement__c WHERE Id =: DriverStatementCreate.Id LIMIT 1];

        System.assertEquals((decimal)SearchTotalEZPass[0].get('Total_EZ_I_Pass_Cost__c'), (decimal)SearchExpenseSumEZPass[0].get('TotalCostEZPass'));

        System.assertEquals('EZ/I Pass', SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c'));

      }

    }

  }

  @isTest static void  testIfRecordEqualMiscellaneousTrue() {

    Account AccountCreate = new Account(Name='Test Account', RecordTypeId='0121U000000WnELQA0');
    insert AccountCreate;

    Opportunity OpportunityCreate = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opportunity', StageName='Active', CloseDate=date.today(), AccountId=AccountCreate.id, RecordTypeId='0121U000000bFCr');
    insert OpportunityCreate;

    Driver_Statement__c DriverStatementCreate = new Driver_Statement__c(Name='Test Driver Statement',Opportunity__c=OpportunityCreate.id, Total_Driver_Gross_Rate__c = 1234.00);
    insert DriverStatementCreate;

    if (DriverStatementCreate.id != null) {

      Expense__c ExpenseCreate1 = new Expense__c(Type__c='Miscellaneous', Cost__c=1235.00, Driver_Statement__c = DriverStatementCreate.id);
      insert ExpenseCreate1;

      List<AggregateResult> SearchExpenseSumMiss = [SELECT SUM(Cost__c)TotalCostMiss FROM Expense__c WHERE Driver_Statement__c =: DriverStatementCreate.Id AND Type__c =: ExpenseCreate1.Type__c];

      List<Expense__c> SearchExpenseType = [SELECT Type__c FROM Expense__c WHERE Id =: ExpenseCreate1.Id];

      if (ExpenseCreate1.Type__c == SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c')) {

        DriverStatementCreate.Total_Miscellaneous_Cost__c = (Decimal)SearchExpenseSumMiss[0].get('TotalCostMiss');
        update DriverStatementCreate;

        List<Driver_Statement__c> SearchTotalMiscellaneous = [SELECT Total_Miscellaneous_Cost__c FROM Driver_Statement__c WHERE Id =: DriverStatementCreate.Id LIMIT 1];

        System.assertEquals((decimal)SearchTotalMiscellaneous[0].get('Total_Miscellaneous_Cost__c'), (decimal)SearchExpenseSumMiss[0].get('TotalCostMiss'));

        System.assertEquals('Miscellaneous', SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c'));

      }

    }

  }

  @isTest static void  testIfRecordEqualTrailerTrue() {

    Account AccountCreate = new Account(Name='Test Account', RecordTypeId='0121U000000WnELQA0');
    insert AccountCreate;

    Opportunity OpportunityCreate = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opportunity', StageName='Active', CloseDate=date.today(), AccountId=AccountCreate.id, RecordTypeId='0121U000000bFCr');
    insert OpportunityCreate;

    Driver_Statement__c DriverStatementCreate = new Driver_Statement__c(Name='Test Driver Statement',Opportunity__c=OpportunityCreate.id, Total_Driver_Gross_Rate__c = 1234.00);
    insert DriverStatementCreate;

    if (DriverStatementCreate.id != null) {

      Expense__c ExpenseCreate1 = new Expense__c(Type__c='Trailer', Cost__c=1235.00, Driver_Statement__c = DriverStatementCreate.id);
      insert ExpenseCreate1;

      List<AggregateResult> SearchExpenseSumTrailer = [SELECT SUM(Cost__c)TotalCostTrailer FROM Expense__c WHERE Driver_Statement__c =: DriverStatementCreate.Id AND Type__c =: ExpenseCreate1.Type__c];

      List<Expense__c> SearchExpenseType = [SELECT Type__c FROM Expense__c WHERE Id =: ExpenseCreate1.Id];

      if (ExpenseCreate1.Type__c == SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c')) {

        DriverStatementCreate.Total_Trailer_Cost__c = (Decimal)SearchExpenseSumTrailer[0].get('TotalCostTrailer');
        update DriverStatementCreate;

        List<Driver_Statement__c> SearchTotalTrailer = [SELECT Total_Trailer_Cost__c FROM Driver_Statement__c WHERE Id =: DriverStatementCreate.Id LIMIT 1];

        System.assertEquals((decimal)SearchTotalTrailer[0].get('Total_Trailer_Cost__c'), (decimal)SearchExpenseSumTrailer[0].get('TotalCostTrailer'));

        System.assertEquals('Trailer', SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c'));

      }

    }

  }

  @isTest static void  testIfRecordEqualTruckTrue() {

    Account AccountCreate = new Account(Name='Test Account', RecordTypeId='0121U000000WnELQA0');
    insert AccountCreate;

    Opportunity OpportunityCreate = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opportunity', StageName='Active', CloseDate=date.today(), AccountId=AccountCreate.id, RecordTypeId='0121U000000bFCr');
    insert OpportunityCreate;

    Driver_Statement__c DriverStatementCreate = new Driver_Statement__c(Name='Test Driver Statement',Opportunity__c=OpportunityCreate.id, Total_Driver_Gross_Rate__c = 1234.00);
    insert DriverStatementCreate;

    if (DriverStatementCreate.id != null) {

      Expense__c ExpenseCreate1 = new Expense__c(Type__c='Truck', Cost__c=1235.00, Driver_Statement__c = DriverStatementCreate.id);
      insert ExpenseCreate1;

      List<AggregateResult> SearchExpenseSumTruck = [SELECT SUM(Cost__c)TotalCostTruck FROM Expense__c WHERE Driver_Statement__c =: DriverStatementCreate.Id AND Type__c =: ExpenseCreate1.Type__c];

      List<Expense__c> SearchExpenseType = [SELECT Type__c FROM Expense__c WHERE Id =: ExpenseCreate1.Id];

      if (ExpenseCreate1.Type__c == SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c')) {

        DriverStatementCreate.Total_Truck_Cost__c = (Decimal)SearchExpenseSumTruck[0].get('TotalCostTruck');
        update DriverStatementCreate;

        List<Driver_Statement__c> SearchTotalTruck = [SELECT Total_Truck_Cost__c FROM Driver_Statement__c WHERE Id =: DriverStatementCreate.Id LIMIT 1];

        System.assertEquals((decimal)SearchTotalTruck[0].get('Total_Truck_Cost__c'), (decimal)SearchExpenseSumTruck[0].get('TotalCostTruck'));

        System.assertEquals('Truck', SearchExpenseType[0].get('Type__c'));

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a unit-test / test class for trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/how-to-write-a-unit-test-test-class-for-trigger). Also if you are facing any specific issue please edit your question and provide the details.

Comment: Again, you should look through [How do I Increase My Code Coverage or Why Can't I Cover These Lines](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: I know that I do not have any code coverage for code in "else if (trigger.isDelete)". But I am not sure how to separate it...

Comment: You have to have a test where you actually delete a record...

Comment: Wow so simple, Thanks Adrian. I added method for deleting and it worked... Did not think about it for some reason...

Comment: you are doing soql in a for loop - your trigger is not bulkified and will fail the moment you run Data Loader on a batch of records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to test the trigger bindings on a delete operation, you must perform a delete operation. As with all test coverage questions, the answer boils down to *get the code to run*.