# Need test class for preventing email change on contact after user has entered the email earlier

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

Apex class:

```
public class Contacttriggerhandler {
    
    public static void preventEmailChange(list<contact> conlist,Map<Id,Contact> myoldmap){
        
        for(Contact newcon: conlist){
            
            Contact oldcon= new Contact();
            oldcon= myoldmap.get(newcon.id);
            if(oldcon.Email!= newcon.Email){
                newcon.Email.addError('invalid email address');
            }
             }
        }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger Contacttriggers on Contact (before insert, before update) {
 system.debug('values of old***' +trigger.oldmap);
     system.debug('values of new###' +trigger.new);
     
     Contacttriggerhandler.preventEmailChange(trigger.new,trigger.oldmap);
     
}
```

Comment: Do these answer your question? [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) and [How to write a unit-test / test class for trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/how-to-write-a-unit-test-test-class-for-trigger)

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issues are you encountering? This community is here to help, not to complete your requirements.