# Trigger getting Coverage on Insert but not Update

Tags: apex, trigger, failing-tests, update

### Why This Question is Necessary:

It is clear that this question get's asked quite a bit on here, but the examples in other questions are oversimplified (for example the post had a "redundancy" flag and posted a post that was extremely simple; if the problem matched that solution, I wouldn't have posted this one). There appears to be a user base that has a deep knowledge of triggers on here, but takes it for granted. It's unclear why this unit test functions the way it does. Some responses requested more source code, but the solution that worked demonstrated that the source code was not needed. I would like to request that this post not be pulled or negatively voted because I think that the solution here is better than some others that post recipes rather than addressing the problem with a practical business solution c.f. a theoretical one. I think this should be used as a foil to address the complexity between `MakeData` and `MakingDataInMethods`. Thank you, feedback is welcomed.

### Begin Problem:

I'm trying to test a simple trigger with a checkbox on the `Contact` that roles up to the `Account`. When `Is_US_Contact__c` is marked `true` it rolls up to `Is_US_Marketing_Contact__c` on the `Account`. The code works as expected, but the coverage is not making sense.

`I can't get the Account value to assert correctly in the code`.

I technically have the code coverage at a minimum, but I want to make sure I understand why this account assertion is not working.

I have tried this with several configurations of `Test.StartTest/Test.StopTest`, but none of them seem to be making a difference. The code does work as expected, but I can't seem to get the assertion correct.

```
@IsTest
public static void testODPUsMarketingChange() {
        //SetupData

        Account a = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account ODP',
            RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Organization').getRecordTypeId()
        );

        insert a;

        Contact odp2 = [
                SELECT
                Id,
                FirstName,
                LastName,
                Is_Legal_Contact__c,
                Is_International_Contact__c,
                Is_US_Contact__c,
                AccountId,
                RecordTypeId
            FROM
                Contact
            WHERE AccountId =: a.Id
        ];
        System.assert(odp2!=NULL);
        System.assert(odp2.Is_US_Contact__c==true);

        odp2.Is_US_Contact__c = false;

        Test.startTest();
            update odp2;
        Test.stopTest();

        Account acct2 = [
            SELECT
                    Id,
                    Is_US_Marketing_Contact__c
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id =: a.Id
        ];
        System.debug('marketing value ' + acct2.Is_US_Marketing_Contact__c );
        System.assertEquals(false,acct2.Is_US_Marketing_Contact__c );

}
```

Comment: `System.assertEquals(newCon.Account.Is_US_Marketing_Contact__c, false, 'Actual Value ' + newCon.Account.Is_US_Marketing_Contact__c );` is this the one?

Comment: Yes. That is the assertion that is failing.

Comment: I have also attempted a standard SOQL query on Account using the Contact Id as the filter, but this fails as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the relevant portions of the trigger code.  Also, have set debug statements in your trigger to see if your unit test record meets the requirements for the trigger to fire?

Comment: I think I figured it out. But I'm not crazy, the design pattern is correct?

Comment: Looks like there is a auto generate contact that get's marked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a unit-test / test class for trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/how-to-write-a-unit-test-test-class-for-trigger)

Comment: No. But appreciate the post. I'm still debugging. Thought I had figured it out, but still having the same behavior.

Comment: Posting your test and asking why it doesn't cover code you don't include, makes it very difficult to answer.

Comment: Code was very very convoluted. The issue was not in the code, but in the UnitTest. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to figure it out with @TestSetup, but I'm not sure why it is the case...probably something to do with @TestSetup not doing updates and inserts in the same context?

Here is the solution that was able to get it to work:

These are all in the same test class `ContactProcesses_Test`

### TestSetup

```
@TestSetup
    static void makeData(){
        Account a = new Account(
                Name = 'Test Account ODP',
                RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Organization').getRecordTypeId()
        );

        insert a;
    }
```

### Test Method

```
@IsTest
    public static void testODPUsMarketingChange() {
        //SetupData
        Account a = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account ODP'];


        Contact odp2 = [
                SELECT
                        Id,
                        FirstName,
                        LastName,
                        Is_Legal_Contact__c,
                        Is_International_Contact__c,
                        Is_US_Contact__c,
                        AccountId,
                        RecordTypeId
                FROM
                        Contact
                WHERE AccountId = :a.Id
        ];
        System.assert(odp2 != NULL);
        System.assert(odp2.Is_US_Contact__c == true);

        odp2.Is_US_Contact__c = false;

        Test.startTest();
        update odp2;
        Test.stopTest();

        Account acct2 = [
                SELECT
                        Id,
                        Is_US_Marketing_Contact__c
                FROM Account
                WHERE Id = :a.Id
        ];
        System.debug('marketing value ' + acct2.Is_US_Marketing_Contact__c);
        System.assertEquals(false, acct2.Is_US_Marketing_Contact__c);
    }
```

Comment: I'm still not sure why this works...but it does. Does anyone have any thoughts on why it would work with `MakeData` but not in the test method itself?