# Hi am new for Salesforce Please help with write test class for My trigger handler Class

Tags: unit-test, deployment, code-coverage, field-update, after-trigger

Trigger

```
trigger AuditRecCreationFromBilling on Billing__c (after insert , after update) {
    
    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
        AuditRecCreationFromBillingHandler.InsertRecord(trigger.new);
    }
    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
        AuditRecCreationFromBillingHandler.UpdateRecord(trigger.new, trigger.OldMap);
    }
}
```

Trigger Handler

```
public class AuditRecCreationFromBillingHandler {

    public static void InsertRecord(List<Billing__c> billList){
    List<Audit__c> auList = new List<Audit__c>(); 


    Id rtId1=Schema.SObjectType.Audit__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Income').getRecordTypeId();
    Id rtId2=Schema.SobjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Consulting').getRecordTypeId();
    Id rtId3=Schema.SobjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Development').getRecordTypeId();
    Id rtId4=Schema.SobjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Support').getRecordTypeId();
    Id rtId5=Schema.SobjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Training').getRecordTypeId();
    Set<id> Ids = new Set<id>();
    String Name;
        Decimal Amount;
        String Voucher;
        Date Received;
    for(Billing__c b1:billList){
                if(b1.Payment_Status__c =='Received'||b1.Payment_Status__c=='Partially Received'){
    Ids.add(b1.Opportunity_Billings__c);
                Name=b1.Name;
                Amount=b1.Actual_Received__c;
                Voucher=b1.Name;
                Received=b1.Received_Date__c; 
            }
        }
    system.debug(Ids);
        for(Opportunity opp: [select id,RecordTypeId from Opportunity where Id=:Ids])
            {
                system.debug(opp);
                Audit__c a = new Audit__c();
                    a.RecordTypeId = rtId1;
    a.Name__c=Name;
                    a.Amount__c=Amount;
                    a.Date__c=Received;
                    a.Group__c = 'Revenue';
                    a.Transaction_Type__c = 'Business';
                    a.Voucher_Type__c=Voucher;
                if(Opp.RecordTypeId==rtId2){            
                     a.Classification__c='Consulting';             
                }
    Else if(Opp.RecordTypeId==rtId3){
                    a.Classification__c='Development';
                }                
                Else if(Opp.RecordTypeId==rtId4){                   
                     a.Classification__c='Support';                   
                }
                Else if(Opp.RecordTypeId==rtId5){
                    a.Classification__c='Training';
                }
                auList.add(a);
        }
        insert auList;
    }
    public static void UpdateRecord(List<Billing__c> bList,Map<id,Billing__c> bOldMap){
        List<Audit__c> auUpList = new List<Audit__c>();
        Id rtId1=Schema.SObjectType.Audit__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Income').getRecordTypeId();
        Id rtId2=Schema.SobjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Consulting').getRecordTypeId();
        Id rtId3=Schema.SobjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Development').getRecordTypeId();
        Id rtId4=Schema.SobjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Support').getRecordTypeId();
        Id rtId5=Schema.SobjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Training').getRecordTypeId();
    Set<id> Ids = new Set<id>();
        String Name;
        Decimal Amount1;
        Decimal Amount2;
        String Voucher;
        Date Received;
        for(Billing__c b2:bList){
            if(b2.Payment_Status__c=='Received'){
                if(b2.Actual_Received__c!=bOldMap.get(b2.Id).Actual_Received__c){
                   Amount1=bOldMap.get(b2.Id).Actual_Received__c;
                }
            }         
        }
    for(Billing__c b3:bList){
            Ids.add(b3.Opportunity_Billings__c);
            Amount2=b3.Actual_Received__c;
        }
        for(Opportunity opp: [select id,RecordTypeId from Opportunity where Id=:Ids]){
            Audit__c a1 = new Audit__c();
                    a1.RecordTypeId = rtId1;
                    a1.Name__c=Name;
                    a1.Amount__c=Amount2-Amount1;
                    a1.Date__c=Received;
                    a1.Group__c = 'Revenue';
                    a1.Transaction_Type__c = 'Business';
                    a1.Voucher_Type__c=Voucher;
     if(Opp.RecordTypeId==rtId2){           
                     a1.Classification__c='Consulting';             
                }
                Else if(Opp.RecordTypeId==rtId3){
                    a1.Classification__c='Development';
                }                
                Else if(Opp.RecordTypeId==rtId4){                   
                     a1.Classification__c='Support';                   
                }
                Else if(Opp.RecordTypeId==rtId5){
                    a1.Classification__c='Training';
        }
            auUpList.add(a1);
     }
        insert auUpList;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. This is not a free coding service and we expect you to show that you have tried to answer the problem for yourself.

Comment: ...or this? [How to write a unit-test / test class for trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/10988/81648)